# Tailing Logfile in Ruby On Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have some scripts which i have to execute from my ruby on rails application. To ensure that scripts do what they should, my application *must* show/tail the content of logfiles which where generated from the scripts.

In more detail: i have expect scripts which configure some blackbox devices over a seriell connection (some sort of a rollout mechanism). So i have to watch, for example, a update process or a reboot of the connected device (to verify that everything is okay). This is what i write to my logfiles.

Therefore i need to:

1. execute a process and handle the exit code
2. tail a/some logfiles (maybe Javascript or html5?)

How could i do that? Examples will be really appreciate!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to #1 is pretty easy,  the system call, i.e.

```
ret = system('ls','-l')
```

ret will be true if the command had a zero exit status.  $?  will contain a Process::Status object from which you can obtain the exit status

```
unless system('ls','-l','/a_bogus_dir')
  logger.debug("ls failed with #{$?.exitstatus}")
end
```

The answer for #2 can be done several ways.  You could create a controller action that simply grabbed the contents of a specific file in the filesystem,  and returned the contents.

```
def get_file_contents
  File.open(params[:file_to_read],"r") { |f| @contents = f.read }
  respond_to |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then create the file get_file_contents.js.erb:

```
$('#display_div').html('<%= escape_javascript(@contents) %>');
```

Then you'd have to create a timer of some kind on your page to repeatedly call that controller action,  I use jquery.timers.  In a timer loop you would call

```
$.get('/get_file_contents?file_to_read=public/logfile');
```

That will hit the controller,  grab the file contents,  and execute get_file_contents.js.erb,  which would update the div with the current contents of the file.

You'd have to add the route /get_file_contents to routes.rb.

Comment: Sorry. Sadly ive bite on granite here. Didnt get it working. It doesnt show any updates. It seems to respond with html instead of "js". I have created a file called "get_file_contents.html.erb" additonally, which contains my "display_div" - and your "get_file_contents.js.erb". But ive got an empty website (no html in it).